# What is Service Credentials Negotiation?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I study  microsoft explanation about Service Credentials Negotiation.. but i don't understand What is Service Credentials Negotiation and when we should use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Negotiation is the process of establishing trust between a client and
>   a service by exchanging credentials. The process is performed
>   iteratively between the client and the service, so as to disclose only
>   the information necessary for the next step in the negotiation
>   process. In practice, the end result is the delivery of a service's
>   credential to the client to be used in subsequent operations. With one
>   exception, by default the system-provided bindings in WCF negotiate
>   the service credential automatically when using message-level
>   security. (The exception is the BasicHttpBinding, which does not
>   enable security by default.) To disable this behavior, see the
>   [NegotiateServiceCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagesecurityoverhttp.negotiateservicecredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [NegotiateServiceCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.federatedmessagesecurityoverhttp.negotiateservicecredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836(v=vs.110).aspx

So, by default the system-provided bindings in WCF negotiate the service credential automatically when using message-level security with exception of BasicHttpBinding and you only need to worry about it if you need to change this default behavior and provision credentials at the client instead of letting the service take care of that for you through process called negotiation...

Comment: Please give me an example that when we should disable this property?

Comment: If you wanted to use Windows credentials/Kerberos authentication instead of SOAP in case both the service and the client are on the Windows domain for example...